# Insert Data with Dropdownlist Condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have asp.net project which has dropdownlist. i need to insert data into my database according to dropdownlist condition.

For example; in my project, i will choose the employee and i will insert the some values from my textboxes and after clicking button on the bottom, i need to insert the changes into database that selected employee from my dropdownlist.

Here is the button click codes;

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string strSQL = "UPDATE info (empid,day1,day2,date1) Values (@empid,@day1,@day2,@date1)";
    string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day1", Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value)));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day1", Int32.Parse(TextBox1.Text)));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day2", Int32.Parse(TextBox2.Text)));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date1", CalendarExtender1.SelectedDate));
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    if (i > 0)
        Response.Write("Data Inserted");
    else
        Response.Write("Try Again");

}
```

Here is something to make clear on your mind;

|Dropdownlist1| (i will click here and names will appear you know.)

-Mike

-John

-Susan

-Kevin

(label1) DAY1 : ***_*__*_*__** (TEXTBOX1)

(label2) DAY2: ***_*__*_*__** (TEXTBOX2)

|FINISH| (button1)

You see from here, i will click dropdownlist and i will choose the employee. After i will enter the values and i will click on FINISH button and data will be inserted into that selected employee.

Here is the key question; how can i tell the button_click event; you will insert these data's into selected employees table which i have chosen the employee from dropdownlist. okay ?

I tried to make sample of the table here;

ID   NAME   TYPE   MON   TUE .... SUN   TOTAL   DAY1    DAY2   DATE

---

1    mike   out    250   350 ..... 0     900      -      -      22-06-2012

2    john   in     350   150 .... 100   1100      -      -      28-06-2012

As you see from here my friend, i will choose the dates from my datetimepickers, i will choose the employee from my dropdownlist and i will enter the values into textboxes and after that i will click finish button.

the day1,day2 values must be inserted into that chosen employee.

waiting your answer please, i need it too badly..

thanks.

Waiting your helps with four eye.
Thanks.

Did you understand what i mean my friends ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you did not set the dropdownlist's `SelectedValue`, you should set it to be the employee's id.

Then, modify your function to also take into account the value in the dropdownlist like this:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    string strSQL = "Insert INTO info (id, day1,day2) Values (@id, @day1,@day2)";
    string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", Int32.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue)));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day1", TextBox1.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day2", TextBox2.Text));

    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    ....
}
```

Notice the change is using the `SelectedValue` property of the DropdownList to find the correct Id

Comment: Dropdownlist ID value must come from the relevant table right ?

Comment: Yes, the id should be the employee id... so when you choose "Mike' the value should be "1" (for example)

Comment: Mate, it says that error : " Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'bilgiler3' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." I understand from this error, i need to change it to ON. But it means its going to create new rows for my insert command, it will not change an existing employee's values. Isnt it ?

Comment: correct. For an existing row use *UPDATE bilgiler3* instead of *INSERT INTO*

Comment: My friend, your answer is really usefull for me, thanks for this but. I have date column you know. i need to update that selected date's and selected employee's column.
Look at my first entry and answer me please. I made some changes on my code side. Can you check and answer me please.

Comment: @KuthayGumus - I'm not sure I understand what the date column has to do with the dropdownlist... Since your initial question on how to *"Insert data with Dropdownlist condition"* - If you're still having the same problem of fetching a value from a dropdownlist, please explain the specific problem. If this is *a new question*- please open a new question with the specific problem you have now and we will gladly help you :)

Comment: thanks,
i will open new topic if i website give chance my friend.:))

Comment: after taking answer from my second topic, the asp.net page will be working fully :)

Answer (score 1):

You can insert the selected employee value in database by geting the selected value of dropdown list.

```
int empID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlEmployee.SelectedValue);
SqlConnection conn;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
string strSQL = "Insert INTO info (empid, day1,day2) Values (@empid, @day1,@day2)";
string bag_str = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["asgdb01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
conn = new SqlConnection(bag_str);
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = strSQL;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@empid", empID));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day1", TextBox1.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@day2", TextBox2.Text));

int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Okay, i get the value like this method;
string employee = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
what will be the sql command then my friend ? Can you tell more about it ?
"Insert INTO Insert INTO info (day1,day2) Values (@day1,@day2) ............ ?? ";

Can you help about it ?